# Examples of higher dimensional TQFTs

Tags: category-theory, manifolds, mathematical-physics, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory

1-dimensional TQFT's assign to every 1-manifold (disjoint union of circles) a vector space and to every surface a linear map between the vector spaces that correspond to the boundary manifolds. So this is a functor from the cobordism category of 1-manifolds to the category of vector spaces. What are some examples of higher dimensional TQFT's? ie functors from the cobordism category of n-manifolds to the category of vector spaces.

Comment: As already said, two dim TQFT corresponds to Frobenius algebra, because every surface has a "pair of pants" decomposition. The simplest example of $2$ dim TQFT I know : take a triangulated surface, a vector space $V$, an element $a \in V \otimes V \otimes V$ and a contraction $\mu \in V^* \otimes V^*$. Triangulating your surface, you can put a copy of $a$ on every triangle, taking the big tensor product of all $a$ and using edges for contracting. You will end with a scalar which is an invariant of the surface. $a$ and $\mu$ have to verify some conditions (invariance under Pachner moves).

Answer (score 2):

Two dimensional non-extended TQFTs correspond to Frobenius algebras and there's a [book](http://mat.uab.es/~kock/TQFT/FS.pdf) about that (only the short version is linked tho).

*Extended* TQFTs are a technically more daunting, but conceptually easier to define gadget: if you believe [this](http://www-math.mit.edu/~lurie/papers/cobordism.pdf) paper (you should; a more user-friendly presentation is contained in [this](http://algant.eu/documents/theses/zhao.pdf) master thesis) the $\infty$-category (in some model: the paper uses Segal spaces -am I right?-) of $n$-dimensional cobordisms happen to be the free symmetric monoidal $(\infty,n)$-category on a single generator.

For what I can understand and remember, the issue with the nonextended version is that without higher category theory you cannot properly address [Baez-Dolan conjecture](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/cobordism.pdf). As the dimension goes up and up, you can not expect to have a nice classification of the manifolds in your cobordism category in terms of "generators and relations" as it happens in dimension two.

Three-dimensional TQFTs are studied in a beautiful, but difficult, [book](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/461906) by Turaev, because of their link with knot theory, but I would appear ridicolous if I attempted to explain more.

All this material, however, comes from my bad memory and from a rather unthoughtful googling operation: you can certainly find something that suits better your curiosity if you interrogate it too (Plus, I'm far from being an expert in each of the things I cited.) :)

There are, in fact, several different approached to the subject, and it might be dispersive not to choose one on which you want to concentrate first: just to mention one, https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1079